# VB.NET does not execute SQL queries correctly

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I am doing some assignments at school where we are supposed to connect to a database using VB.NET, but my SQL queries does not do what they are supposed to do.

```
        tilkobling.Open()

        Dim sql As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM personer WHERE fornavn='@navn';", tilkobling)
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text)
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim intern_tabell As New DataTable

        da.SelectCommand = sql
        da.Fill(intern_tabell)

        tilkobling.Close()
```

I have tried hardcoding the SQL queries with 'william', my own name and a name that I know for sure is in the database, but both the parameterized and the hardcoded option does nothing, not even an error.

I'm also using this SQL query in my code: `Dim sql As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM personer ORDER BY @row;", tilkobling)`, but that seems to ignore my `ORDER BY` command, and executes only the SELECT command; again, without errors.

EDIT:

After populating the DataTable, I add all the rows from the DataTable to a ListBox.

```
 For Each rad As DataRow In intern_tabell.Rows
            ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", rad("id"), rad("fornavn"), rad("etternavn")))
        Next rad
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like a typo. "@navn" is not the same as "@name" on the line below. They need to match. Pretty sure you can't use the value of a parameter to change the ORDER BY clause either.

Comment: Side note, you should wrap your disposable objects in Using statements ie `Using sql as New MySqlCommand(...) ... End Using` and you should avoid `AddWithValue`

Comment: @ADyson Oh, ok. Haha, I didn't noticed, I've fixed that now, but nothing happens now either. :/

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I will try to do that after I've fixed this problem, unless that might actually solve the problem itself?

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing happens"? What are you doing with the data once you've populated the DataTable?

Comment: Also, `fornavn='@navn'`. Pretty sure you don't need the quotes round @navn. Assuming this is a string parameter, the parameter binder will take care of that for you. See the example here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: I'll do an edit to show what I do with the data. :)
I mean that ``WHERE fornavn=@navn`` or ``WHERE fornavn='william'`` doesn't give me any results at all (even though there is a column in my database with the name fornavn and the value william.

Comment: @ADyson I removed the single-quotation marks around ``@navn``, and it worked! Now only the ORDER BY won't work properly.

Comment: @gloriousCatnip as I already pointed out you can't use a MySQL variable to specify the field in an ORDER BY. It has to be fixed, or you have to use your .NET code to build the SQL string and vary it like that.

Comment: @ADyson So simply creating the string first, and then passing that string as the SQL command?

Comment: It works now! Thank you all! I ended up using a DataView, that made it a whole lot easier. :)